# Is it good practice to declare authorization credentials in plain text?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth

Is it good practice to declare GCP application authorization credentials, i.e. Client ID and Client Secret in plain text?

I've been working on a Windows desktop app with C#, which involves uploading a file to Google Drive. My real concern is that when I've got to publish the app, the *application's* Client ID/Client Secret shall be disclosed, as I've stored them as variables in the app. Is it safe? Or is there any other, better way to store them in your app while authorizing it with GCP?

Comment: Quick answer (without the level of details @LukeBriner provided): **no, it's not safe, it's completely unsafe and anyone can easily see those credentials**

Comment: The application uploads the files to **their** Drive. But doesn't my app need to authorize itself with GCP, so that users can sign in to it?

Comment: You do that with the OAuth 2.0 PKCE flow (Authorization Code flow). You only need the ClientId there, **not** a ClientSecret. The ClientId is public, so you don't need to worry about it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto And how do you implement PKCE in GCP?

Comment: I don't know, I have never consumed Google services. A quick google search should bring up good results though, like "google cloud drive c# user authentication"

Comment: FYI: you don't need gcp to connect to google drive api.

Comment: @DaImTo yeah. Once you publish your app, you don't need GCP. I was talking about when in the `testing` phase, so you have to share your app credentials with test users whom you 'should' trust but yeah..

Comment: @LakshayaU. you should never share your client id and client secret with anyone this is against TOS.  This includes test users.   Test user should run your app they they do not need credentials if the app has them properly stored within it.

Comment: Ahhhh figured it out. Thanks @DaImTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear we are talking about `application credentials` created on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) (client id and client secret) and not `user credentials` (refresh token, access token) which are created when the user consents to an applications access to their data.

If you check googles TOS you will notice that it states.

[Subject: Changes to the Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html)

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

This also applies to desktop applications.  You should not include for example a settings file in your application which a user could open in clear text and see your client id and client secrets.  It should be compiled into your application (yes the app could be decompiled and the use could get them that way) or better yet stored on your server so that your application can then request it as needed.  This however is not optimal if your application is designed to work offline as well.

Google is aware that there is a gray area with regards to credentials being compiled into applications.  It is considered to be an acceptable risk.  (I had a conversation with the Oauth team a number of years ago about this)

## why you should protect your credentials.

The main issue is that if someone does get your client id and client secret they can then use it and google has no way of knowing its not you.  To make matters worse neither do the users of the app.  So if they start spamming or leaking data its your app that will be to blame and you.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is about the user authorising the use of their resources to the application. If this is an application that other people are using that is sending files to their Google Drives, then they should enter their *own* credentials into the app.

If the app is used by others to upload files to *your* Google Drive, then OAuth is not the correct way to do that for the reason you describe. Instead, you probably need some kind of API for the desktop application to call, which can hide credentials to access Google Drive from the end-user. You will then have a different auth question about making sure only the people you intend to call the API call it.

It's quite a complicated question really.

Comment: Application credentials  are created within [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) by the developer of the application.   Users of your application should not be expected to set up an application in developer console and verify it. This is unrealistic considering that they would have to register a domain in order to host privacy policy and websites for an app they just want to run.  I think you are confusing user credentials and application credentials.   There for this does not answer the question asked.